# How Caitanya Mahaprabhu and Swaminarayan are viewed in the Srivaishnava Sect

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, chaitanya, swaminarayan

The followers of Gaudiya Vaishnavism and Uddhava Sampradaya claim that Caitanya Mahaprabhu and Swaminarayan respectively, are incarnations of Sri Krishna.

Are there any references made by Srivaishnava Acharyas, that accept such claims?

(It would be better for Srivaishnavas to answer this question, but all are welcome!)

Comment: Sri Vaishnavas respect Acharyas of other sects, but I don’t know any Sri Vaishnava works that refer to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu or Swaminarayan as incarnations.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes they sure do! I am a Srivaishnava myself... Vadakalai to be precise... and you are Thenkalai I suppose?

Comment: Oh cool, my Dad’s a Thenkalai and my Mom’s a Vadakalai, so I’m a Thenkalai by birth, but my beliefs lean more to the Vadakalai side.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan oh! It’s the opposite for me... My mom is Thenkalai and my dad is Vadakalai... So I’m a Vadakalai too...

Comment: They have digressed from main tenets so acharyas wont have good view on those. Swaminarayana is off shoot of Vashistha advaita and Caitanya probably of Madhwa. So just decide yourself if they are adhering to original siddhanta and practices. See their temples etc.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I am a Srivaishnava myself, and I can clearly observe that the Swaminarayan Sampradaya (or Ramananda Sampradaya) is NOT AT ALL close to the traditions and ritual customs that we follow today... For example, they emphasise on Radha and Goloka, which we don’t believe in... Also, they have five Tattvas in their philosophy, while we have three...

Comment: @HayagreevRam their temples you should visit for a few days and find out. Same with ISCKON etc... Since the founders Madhwa and rAmAnuja lived before these so only present scholars can comment on it. But its best to get first hand experience yourself

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I am not aware of SwamiNarayan sect, but Gaudiya sect especially ISKCON and Udupi Mutt(Madhvacharya's) are in good relation. Madhva's gurus acknowledge the differences that exist in both. Still they focus on many common things and have a healthy relationship. I don't think they view Chaitanya as an incarnation, but definitely as a great saint. Pejavar mutt of Udupi even held Chaitanya Jayanti festival when they were in charge of Udupi temple. They also allow ISKCON to have a  book stall in Udupi temple premises. On certain occasions they invite ISKCON  for HariNam Sankirtan.